# images won't fade in after one fades out

Tags: javascript, html, css

My slider image fades out but then another one does not appear despite the fadeIn being applied. I also made a function for it to loop but it won't work.Only the first image fades in and out but nothing else afterwards.

js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qust3upk/3/

```
<div id="slider">
            <img id="pic1" src="images/main-banner.png" alt="main banner" class="main_banner">
            <img id="pic2" src="images/nutrition-banner.png" alt="nutrition banner" class="main_banner ">
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="previous">Previous</a>
        <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>



<script type="text/javascript">

sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider  #pic1').fadeIn(300);
    startSlider();


});

function startSlider(){
    count = $('#slider img').size();
    loop = setInterval(function(){

    $('#slider img').fadeOut(300);
    $('#slider img#' + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

    sliderInt = sliderNext;
    sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;

    }, 3000)



}


</script>
```

Comment: are you getting any error messages?

Comment: You need a semicolon after "3000)" --> , 3000);

Comment: you have no numeric ID in html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rewrite this code block:

```
loop = setInterval(function(){

$('#slider img').fadeOut(300);
$('#slider img#' + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

sliderInt = sliderNext;
sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;

}, 3000)
```

As:

```
loop = setInterval(function(){

$('#slider img').fadeOut(300);
$('#slider img#pic' + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

sliderInt = sliderNext;
sliderNext = (sliderNext === count) ? sliderNext = 1 : sliderNext + 1;

}, 3000); //You should have a semicolon here
```

Comment: I have only two images in the slider. The ++ you put works but i notice the same second image is the one that keeps appearing instead of restarting to the first image,etc Also i changed the id in the html for the images to be 1 and 2 since that was a mistake pointed out by one of the users here.

Comment: Did this answer really worked?  I tried it but it won't.  Just wondering

Comment: I modified it but he gave me an idea. Instead of ++, i still left it at + 1. And i made an if statement:if(sliderNext>count){
   sliderNext = 1;
   sliderInt = 1;
 }

Comment: OK...works out the same. Just remember when you get to the last image, you need to start over and move sliderInt to image1...as long as you do that any number of images will work

Comment: @Ralphunreal....also I suggest you use length() instead of size(), as size() is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the images by the wrong id.  Try:

```
$('#slider #pic' + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);
```

Also, you aren't using your 'count' variable.  Also change to this:

```
sliderNext = (sliderNext % count) + 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call a function right after the fadeOut effect like this

```
   $('#slider img').fadeOut(300, function(){
       $('#slider img#' +).fadeIn(300);
    });
```

You can read more details from here [jquery.fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

But of course you need to also need to have correct reference.

In your code the referencing to the `img` tags are not correctly done.  That is why only the first image fades in and out and then stops.

This line of code `$('#slider img').fadeOut(300);` it will fadeOut all the `img` tags.
And then this line of code `$('#slider img#' + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);` will fade in an `img` with the id of 1 (`id="1"`) but in your html it's `id="pic1"` .

***Here is a version of your code that works (I did modify it a little bit and fix those references)***

```
<script>
var sliderNext = 1;

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#slider  img#pic' + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);
    startSlider();
});

function startSlider(){
    var count = jQuery('#slider img.main_banner').size();
    loop = setInterval(function(){
       jQuery('#slider  img#pic' + sliderNext).fadeOut(300, function(){
           sliderNext += 1;
           if(sliderNext > count){
            sliderNext = 1;
           }
           jQuery('#slider img#pic' + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);
        });
    }, 3000)
}
</script>
```